# It is possible to rename "lib" directory of local Dart dependency without imports breaking?

Tags: dart

My Dart project consists from the three modules:

- `BusinessRules` - obviously, the business rules
- `Client` - client application
- `Server` - serve application

[image]

Both `Client` and Server depends on `BusinessRules`.
Currently the `BusinessRules` has two classes: `Task` and `User`:

[image]

The `Task` could be imported to `Server` project as:

```
import "package:business_rules/Enterprise/Task.dart";
```

If to set aside the guidelines during this question, can I rename the `lib` directory in `BusinessRules` without loss of visibility of this class and application crash? I suppose some setup will required - it's O'K.

### Important point

- None of these packages will be published as library.
- I know that valid Dart package name could not include the uppercase symbols (so, the `BusinessRules` called `business_rules` in it's `pubspec.yaml`). However, I reserve the right to name the directories as I want.